# How to achieve Vista glass transparency (AERO) in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-vista, aero

It's easy for a WPF application to make parts of a window transparent or semi-transparent. But how to I apply the current Vista theme (colors, opacity) to these transparent parts?

When I have a green glass border how will I get a green glass background of the same style?

Is it even possible to do this without calls to the Windows API?

I am thinking of [something like this](http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/continuum/)

Comment: Isn't that the color of the background, that is making its mark? And not the theme color?

Comment: @MartinHN The theme adds a tint to the glass but the background will still show through depending on how transparent the glass is supposed to be in the theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice example:

CodeProject: [Adding Glass Effect to WPF using Attached Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFGlass.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link, look for the section titled "IE7 – Extending the glass frame":

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation on extending the Aero glass effect in your WPF app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx