# Model Transperency

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I achieve transparency on a model?

Comment: i guess this question is a little bit 'unprecise'. what model are you talking about? viewmodels with wpf? what do you mean with transparency? if you refine your question, the chances of getting a good answer will increase ;)

Comment: sorry, I am using this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewport3d.aspx

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  You own the question, which means you should update the question to add details and delete your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/pantal/archive/2007/07/23/sorting-for-wpf-3d-transparency.aspx

[How to achieve Vista glass transparency (AERO) in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633817/how-to-achieve-vista-glass-transparency-aero-in-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0):

set its background property to be transparent :)