# Semi-transparent WPF window, blur the background (desktop, not static image)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to solve this for a while, with a lot of searching and asking.
I am using WPF and I have a semi-transparent window. Basically I want it to look like frosted glass.
I am new to WPF, so I assume that I cannot apply any shaders/effects to the pixels visible on the semi-transparent background, but only to the elements that I add to the window.

Thus I must capture a screenshot of the background, and place it there and make it look like it's a "window".

The problem is this: Taking the screenshot of the screen excluding my own window.
Obviously, I can hide it and show it once the screenshot is taken, but this won't work if the user is moving the window.

I wanted to ask again, because I haven't found any real solution to this problem.

My last effort was to install the directx sdk and apply my own shaders, but it doesnt seem like they affect anything through the window.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of:

[How to achieve Vista glass transparency (AERO) in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633817/how-to-achieve-vista-glass-transparency-aero-in-a-wpf-application)

This example from Code Project seems to work:

https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpfglass.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for something more customizable. I tried that one before, and as I changed its parameters, my windows machine's glass also changed.